# How can I remove m² and convert ha into m²?

Tags: python, thonny

Sorry for the basic question, I just started learning and I find this quite difficult. Example I got a list where there are area sizes and I need to make them all m² so I have to somehow multiply ha by 10 000.

```
{
 '17001:003:0009': '712 m²', '17001:003:0010': '1694 m²',
 '33101:004:0568': '2070 m²', '33101:003:0502': '3553 m²', 
 '33101:003:0503': '2308 m²', '69403:002:0317': '23.95 ha', 
 '69403:001:0263': '8.76 ha', '33101:001:0197': '5.05 ha', 
 '33101:003:0550': '2.65 ha', '33101:004:0596': '2.45 ha'
}
```

Comment: You need to give better explanation of what you are trying to do. We can't see your computer so we don't know what you are learning! Are you asking how to split string on space? Retrieve items from a Python dictionary? Or do you actually need to calculate some unit conversions?

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the keys and values and test for `ha` at the end of the values.  Process accordingly.  Note there are 10K m²/ha.

```py
from pprint import pprint

d = {
 '17001:003:0009': '712 m²', '17001:003:0010': '1694 m²',
 '33101:004:0568': '2070 m²', '33101:003:0502': '3553 m²', 
 '33101:003:0503': '2308 m²', '69403:002:0317': '23.95 ha', 
 '69403:001:0263': '8.76 ha', '33101:001:0197': '5.05 ha', 
 '33101:003:0550': '2.65 ha', '33101:004:0596': '2.45 ha'
}

for k,v in d.items():
    num = float(v[:-2])
    d[k] = num * 10_000 if v.endswith('ha') else num

pprint(d)
```

Output:

```
{'17001:003:0009': 712.0,
 '17001:003:0010': 1694.0,
 '33101:001:0197': 50500.0,
 '33101:003:0502': 3553.0,
 '33101:003:0503': 2308.0,
 '33101:003:0550': 26500.0,
 '33101:004:0568': 2070.0,
 '33101:004:0596': 24500.0,
 '69403:001:0263': 87600.0,
 '69403:002:0317': 239500.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way will retain the type and style of the values:

```
from pprint import pprint

D = {
    '17001:003:0009': '712 m²', '17001:003:0010': '1694 m²',
    '33101:004:0568': '2070 m²', '33101:003:0502': '3553 m²',
    '33101:003:0503': '2308 m²', '69403:002:0317': '23.95 ha',
    '69403:001:0263': '8.76 ha', '33101:001:0197': '5.05 ha',
    '33101:003:0550': '2.65 ha', '33101:004:0596': '2.45 ha'
}

for k, v in D.items():
    if v[-2:] == 'ha':
        D[k] = f'{round(float(v[:-2]) * 10_000)} m²'
pprint(D)

{'17001:003:0009': '712 m²',
 '17001:003:0010': '1694 m²',
 '33101:001:0197': '50500 m²',
 '33101:003:0502': '3553 m²',
 '33101:003:0503': '2308 m²',
 '33101:003:0550': '26500 m²',
 '33101:004:0568': '2070 m²',
 '33101:004:0596': '24500 m²',
 '69403:001:0263': '87600 m²',
 '69403:002:0317': '239500 m²'}
```